# REST Web Service usage in Android

Tags: android, web-services, web

I have got a tutorial on "Build RESTful web services with the Spring 3 MVC HttpMessageConverter feature" here : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/wa-restful/index.html

But I am not sure if android supports this? If yes, how can i call these web services in my android application and use it??

Or do I have to go for JSON and Jesrey, JAVA - RX etc??

Any help??

Thanks,
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

I know of Android applications invoking web services - havent actually worked on such an app though. The actual payload can be JSON or XML - I am assuming you are building the client on the Android device and the server is hosted somewhere else. If this is the case, the API should not be much different from what you use on the desktop to access a web service.

Sravan.

Comment: Thnks Sravan. You are right. But just wanted to know can i use Spring 3 etc. Because for XML and simple web services I have kSOAP instead of SOAP for android